# Silently updating source files of a cordova application

Tags: android, cordova

I'm thinking of checking for updates every time a user opens it and then downloading the updated files (html,js,css,etc.) from my server and replacing the existing files.

Is this possible? (I think it is since the source files are also included in the apk)

Does this violate any Google Play Store policies?

Answer (score 1):

There is a term in policy

> An app downloaded from Google Play may not modify, replace or update
>   its own APK binary code using any method other than Google Play's
>   update mechanism.

Check it out here [developer-content-policy](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html)